# how to integrate sails.js with a project based on mean.js boiler plate

Tags: node.js, sails.js, mean-stack, meanjs

I'm writing an app, which is based on mean.js boiler plate.

The time has come to integrate some realtime features, and a prospect of using sails.js seems very compelling.

I was wandering if anyone has done this sort of integration, having mean.js as the basic stack, and then adding on sails.

If someone has done it - what is involved in this from the integration and configuration stand point?